# Link to uploaded files in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been facing this issue from two weeks ago, please any help.

I create a model with HttpPostedFileBase field to save a file in folder it works for me in Create View very good.

Now I want to make a link to the uploaded file in the details view.

I tried several ways but I could not found a solution.

any help please.

in the model I Defined some parameter and the following for file

```
 [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "C.V")]
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]

        public HttpPostedFileBase CV { get; set; }
```

in the controller i did the following

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                     if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                              {
                            // extract only the fielname
                            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                            // store the file inside ~/Content/LearnObject-Repository folder
                            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/CVs"), fileName);
                            file.SaveAs(path);
                            var fileNameToSaveInDB = @"~/Content/CVs/" + fileName;


                        }


                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More info on what you have actually tried would have been helpful, but here's few simple steps:

Add new property in your model

```
[NotMapped]
public string FileUrl { get; set; }
```

Set the value in the controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    MyModel myModel = db.MyModel.Find(id);
    myModel.FileUrl = ""; // <-- resolve link;
    ...
}
```

and add the link in your view

```
<div class="display-field">
    <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FileUrl)">Link to file</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I updated my question above. but I waan ask should I set a parameter to save file name only? and another one for HttpPostedFileBase ? @Joonas

Comment: Parameter (property) must be an URL (absolute or relative) for downloading to work, so something like this: myModel.FileUrl = "/Content/CVs/" + fileName;

Comment: so I should defined 2 parameter the first one HttpPostedFileBase and the second one as string to save file name am I right?

Comment: Your question was how to "to make a link to the uploaded file". You do not return HttpPostedFileBase to your details view (since it's the file data). Or am I missing something here? In view there could be something like this: <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FileUrl)">Link to file</a>

Comment: Are you saving the link (fileNameToSaveInDB) to database as the variable name suggests? Then you can use that property directly and there is no need for new one :)

Comment: Yes U are right, I want in the view to make a link to the uploaded file... so i should create two parameter.

Comment: thanks alot , but please tell me how I can use fileNameToSaveInDB ,, thanks alot

Comment: Add new property to your model (i.e. string FileName {get;set;}) and set value of fileNameToSaveInDB to that property. Now you have information where the file is saved in db and you can use directly on you view. Remember, do NOT use [NotMapped] attribute in that property, otherwise it won't be saved to DB.